# Python script doesn't open new chrome tab but gives off no error

Tags: python, anaconda3

i've been trying to debug my code for a while now, it's supposed to open a new chrome url as "about:blank" but does nothing. i'm pretty sure its some simple fix like implementing an argument but i can't find anything at all, also i'm using anaconda3 3.9.13 since it comes with a bunch of modules

(this is only a part of the code)

```
# Setup for chrome 
urL = 'https://www.google.com'
chrome_path = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab(urL) 

# Open the new tab
Url2 = 'about:blank'
Url3 = 'https://python.org' # Debug url
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab(Url2)

# Use JavaScript to set the background image of the page
javascript = f"document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\"File://{os.getcwd()}/image.jpg\")';"
webbrowser.get('chrome').open("javascript:" + javascript)
print(os.getcwd()) # Debug thing for directory
```

i have tried a bunch of things such as changing url, printing arguments etc but nothing seems wrong, it just wont open anything. before, it used to only open google.com but windows would give me an "You'll need a new app to open this about link" error

Comment: What's `webbrowser`? Please make a [mre] and if you're using a particular library, add it to the tags. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: hi! webbrowser is a python module that has for description "Interfaces for launching and remotely controlling Web browsers.", i use it to open a new chrome tab and display a local webpage, here's a little example script of it

import webbrowser
urL='https://www.google.com'
chrome_path="C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))

webbrowser.open("https://python.org")

Comment: I doubt you can pass a JS string into a browser instead of a url.

Comment: i think i'll try something else, maybe i can add a html page in my directory and make the python script open that?